# How to do conditional navigation in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, jsx

Hello I'm trying to do conditional navigation in react native.In my project I'm listing a set of courses and categories as a result of an api fetch request.So after clicking on each course/category  it will navigate to different screens.So What I want is on clicking on the `courses` in first screen I will get the `type` of currently selected item that whether it is `course` or `category`. So if selected item is couse I want to navigate to `UnitListing` screen and if it is `category` I want to navigate to `ChapterListing` screen.How is it possible?

**updated**

```
navigatetoPage = (category) =>{

      const page = category.type == "course" ? "UnitListing" : "ChapterListing";
       this.props.navigation.navigate(page, {
              id: category.id,
              type: category.type
       })

 }
render(){
  return(
    <View style={st.main_outer}>
            {this.state.cats.map(category =>

                                 <TouchableOpacity
  style={st.btn} onPress={() => this.navigatetoPage({category})}>
  <Text style={{ color: "#fff" }}>View Course</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
                                 )}
  </View>
  );
}
```

How do I do conditional navigation here? Please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check type like this way and navigate also you can do in jsx. but this is much cleaner

```js
 navigatetoPage(data){
    const page = data.type == "course" ? "UnitListing" : "ChapterListing";
     this.props.navigation.navigate(page, {
            id: data.id,
            type: data.type
     }) 
 }
 
 <TouchableOpacity
  style={st.btn} onPress={() => this.navigatetoPage(data)}>
  <Text style={{ color: "#fff" }}>View Course</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: But I've done mapping over the `responseData` within rendering so how do I get values in  `id: data.id,type: data.type`.Sorry I'm not clear about how to do that.

Comment: can you share more code. I assume you are getting before. because your code already have data.

Comment: I've updated my question please check.Here navigation is not working